# How to ignore NULL or None values when fetching from a Database

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, nonetype

Excuse me if this is an easy fix, I'm very new to python and sqlite3.

Basically my problem is that when I try to fetch the top 3 best average times from my database, it instead outputs 3 Students who have no average time inputted, or NULL/None.

This is my code:

```
print("\n\tTop 3 fastest average times:\n")
print("%-3s%10s%15s%15s%15s" %("Student ID", "Name", "Surname", "Year group", "Average time\n"))

for row in c.execute('SELECT studentID, firstName, surname, yearGroup, averageTime IS NOT NULL FROM Students ORDER BY averageTime LIMIT 3'):
            studentID, firstName, surname, yearGroup, averageTime = row
print("%-3s %15s %15s %15s %15s" %(studentID, firstName, surname, yearGroup, averageTime))
```

I've tried using previous answers from stack overflow but nothing seems to be working. The problem mainly occurs around the 'averageTime IS NOT NULL' part, but I've tried everything; removing IS NOT NULL, changing it to simply NOT NULL, trying None instead, or simply not using it at all.

Any help is appreciated :]
(Also, this is my first question on here so if formatting is off or I've tagged something wrong then let me know)

Comment: You need the WHERE clause. `WHERE averageTime IS NOT NULL`. Do yourself a favour and complete at least an SQL tutorial if you're going to write SQL code.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **WHERE averageTime IS NOT NULL**

```
for row in c.execute('SELECT studentID, firstName, surname, yearGroup, averageTime FROM Students WHERE averageTime IS NOT NULL ORDER BY averageTime LIMIT 3'):
        studentID, firstName, surname, yearGroup, averageTime = row
        print("%-3s %15s %15s %15s %15s" %(studentID, firstName, surname, yearGroup, averageTime))
```